# Yii2 Clean URLs & Action Parameters

Tags: yii2, clean-urls, yii-url-manager

I've enabled clean URLs on my Yii2 application, but I can't seem to get arguments to pass to the action.

I expect this:

> localhost/app/web/a/b/c/d

To map to the following:

> AController->actionB($c, $d)

It's not happening.

Here's my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule . index.php
```

The relevant part of my web.php:

```
'urlManager' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
                'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
                'showScriptName' => false,
                'rules' => array(
                        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                ),
        ],
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, the rule should look something like:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<c>/<d>' => '<controller>/<action>'
```

So if you try to access `localhost/app/web/a/b/c/d`, Yii will call:

```
class AController extends Controller
{
    public function actionB($c, $d)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to get the same can you pl see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73578796/6854117)?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following rule for your urlManager:

```
'rules' => [
    '<a:\w+>/<b:\w+>/<c:\d+>/<d:\d+>' => 'a/b'
],
```

Addressing to `localhost/a/b/c/d` should now call for action **b** inside controller **a** with params **c** and **d**.

Comment: I am trying to get the same can you pl see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73578796/6854117)?

Answer (score -1):

If you are expecting following URL.

localhost/app/web/a/b/c/d

To map to the following:

AController->actionB($c, $d)

you can specify main.php like following example.

You have to set URL rule like i have mentioned in the below example. It should work.

```
'urlManager' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
                'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
                'showScriptName' => false,
                'rules' => [
                        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>/<id:\d+>' => 'a/b/c/d'
                ],
        ],
```

Please let me know if you have still any query.

Comment: Hi, i have similar problem. When i use Your code i have: 'preg_match(): Compilation failed: two named subpatterns have the same name at offset 55'. When i change <id:\d+>/<id:\d+> to <id:\d+>/<id1:\d+> i have: 'Unable to resolve the request "a/b/c/d"'